# ADMA error after mounting root partition

Tags: linux-kernel

We are trying to boot Linux on a custom board based on ARM processor. The kernel executes successfully from both SD card and eMMC but when the kernel tries to mount the root file system, it is able to mount the root partition but hangs after throwing following error:

`[   11.303145] mmc1: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDHC card at address aaaa
    [   11.311651] mmcblk mmc1:aaaa: Card claimed for testing.
    [   11.318832] mmcblk1: mmc1:aaaa SL16G 14.8 GiB
    [   11.341076]  mmcblk1: p1
    [   11.461523] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
    [   11.473340] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:33.
    [   11.488610] devtmpfs: mounted
    [   11.493848] Freeing unused kernel memory: 500K (c0b0d000 - c0b8a000)
    [   11.911302] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (115) terminated with status 1
    [   11.923611] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
    [   11.935367] mmc1: ADMA error
    [   11.941245] sdhci: =========== REGISTER DUMP (mmc1)===========
    [   11.949353] sdhci: Sys addr: 0x00000000 | Version:  0x00000303
    [   11.957510] sdhci: Blk size: 0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000028
    [   11.965688] sdhci: Argument: 0x00440cc0 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
    [   11.973895] sdhci: Present:  0x01fb0206 | Host ctl: 0x00000013
    [   11.982134] sdhci: Power:    0x0000000d | Blk gap:  0x00000000
    [   11.990404] sdhci: Wake-up:  0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
    [   11.998644] sdhci: Timeout:  0x0000000e | Int stat: 0x00000000
    [   12.006822] sdhci: Int enab: 0x02ff000b | Sig enab: 0x02fc000b
    [   12.014939] sdhci: AC12 err: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
    [   12.022978] sdhci: Caps:     0x376fd080 | Caps_1:   0x10002f73
    [   12.030966] sdhci: Cmd:      0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x00000000
    [   12.038910] sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000308b
    [   12.044909] sdhci: ADMA Err: 0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0xae8420c0
    [   12.052861] sdhci: ===========================================`

As a workaround, when I tried to disable ADMA by passing `sdhci.debug_quirks=32832` to kernel command line arguments, the system hangs at following point:

`[    8.076631] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk1p1...`

Can anyone suggest some solution as I am stuck at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a routing issue in DDR which resulted in chip-select of two DDR chips to be continuously asserted. This resulted in a number of random issues including ADMA error on boot. Doing a rework on the board to rectify chip-select issue resulted in removal of this error.